# SetState causes many rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a messenger app and I have a component for the main screen of all the messages. I'm trying to ensure every time a user sends or receives a message, the component renders and updates the `Flatlist` with the last sent message. I have a listener to firebase realtime database to listen for updates. 
I’m using functional components in my app and I think I’m using setState incorrectly because it causes my component to rerender many times. 
I have thoroughly checked the asked questions and none of them seem to relate to my issue. 
Here's my code.

```
const AllMessagesScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        allMessages: []
    });

    const { allMessages } = state;

    const fsdb = firebase.firestore().collection('Users');
    const db = database().ref(`messages/${uid}`); //realtime database

    const get = async () => {

        try {
            await db.on('value', snapshot => {

                snapshot.forEach(item => {

                    const { key: _id } = item;
                    const { lastMessage } = item.val();

                    fsdb.doc(_id).get().then((doc => {
                        const otherUser = doc.data();
                        const newChat = {
                            id: _id,
                            name: otherUser.name,
                            picture: otherUser.pictures.thumbnailUrl,
                            lastMessage: lastMessage
                        };
                        setState(prevState => ({
                             allMessages: [...prevState.allMessages, newChat]
                        }));
                    })).catch((err) => {
                        console.log('caught', err)
                    });
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error caught', err)
        };

    };

    useEffect(() => {
        get();

    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <FlatList
                data={allMessages}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <MessageCard
                            id={item.id}
                            name={item.name}
                            image={item.picture}
                            lastMessageText={item.lastMessage.text}
                        />
                    </View>
                )}
            />

        </View>
    );

}
```

I have also tried setting the state this way

```
setState({ allMessages: [...allMessages, newUser] });
``
The second way only shows the last rendered message and gets rid of the rest.
Any help is really appreciated
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not update state in a loop, take out the `setState` from inside the loop and call it after the loop.

On each `state` update `React` will `re-render` the `component`, in this case `React` will `re-render` the `component` after each iteration, Which can cause unexpected result.

You have couple of other issue as well that I would like to highlight.

1. You should not use state like `const { allMessages } = state;` it will always give you an empty array on each render. use it like `state.allMessages` whenever is needed.
2. On each rendr you are getting the `database` connection which can cause memory leak, use `useRef` to hold the `db` connection.
3. Initialized the db connection and other stuff inside the `useEffect` hook (on component mount).

I have updated the code which will solve the above issues (I have changed the `then` block with await as you are you async/await in your code and replaced `forEach` with `for of`).

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
const AllMessagesScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        allMessages: []
    });
    let fsdb = useRef();
    let db = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        fsdb.current = firebase.firestore().collection('Users');
        db.current = database().ref(`messages/${uid}`); //realtime database
        fetchMessage();
    }, []);
    async function fetchMessage() {
        try {
            await db.current.on('value', snapshot => {
                let newChat = []
                for (const item of snapshot) {
                    const { key: _id } = item;
                    const { lastMessage } = item.val();
                    let doc = await fsdb.current.doc(_id).get();
                    const otherUser = doc.data();
                    newChat.push({
                        id: _id,
                        name: otherUser.name,
                        picture: otherUser.pictures.thumbnailUrl,
                        lastMessage: lastMessage
                    });
                }
                setState(prevState => ({
                    allMessages: [...prevState.allMessages, ...newChat]
                }));
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error caught', err)
        };
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <FlatList
                data={state.allMessages}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <MessageCard
                            id={item.id}
                            name={item.name}
                            image={item.picture}
                            lastMessageText={item.lastMessage.text}
                        />
                    </View>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sohail. I have tried that but for some reason allMessages never gets updated and is always an empty array. are you sure that is the right way to set the state?

Comment: Thanks @Sohail. I have tried that and now getting an error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...tor" : "@@iterator"]();...')

Comment: Sorry to confuse you it's a warning but my FlatList isnt rendered. Theres no  line number either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211043/discussion-between-sohail-and-abdi).